# adminbro Filter content for listing

Tags: node.js, admin-bro

I am creating an admin panel with a database that has a lot of types of data within one collection.

I am using mongodb and adminbro and mongoose!

types of data under the same collectoin are vehicules with the type of (cars, buses, boats ), and I have several pages for each one of them, for example If I want to add a car I will go to the cars tab, same for the ohters.

I would like to show the cars only when I go to the "cars", right now whenever I go to the cars option I will get all the vehicules not only the car!

This is the following code that I have tried to run in the before and after hook:

```
const displayOnlyCars = () => {
return {
    ...request,
    query: {
        ...request.query,
        'filters.type': 'car'
    }
}
```

Using AdminBro 4.0.1

Comment: Hey, which version of AdminJS are you using?

Comment: using adminbro v 4.0.1

Comment: I believe your solution would be to upgrade to new AdminJS version first: https://www.npmjs.com/package/adminjs